# How do I prove that if A is a matrix of rank 1 then any nonzero vector in the image of A is an eigenvector of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

I literally have no idea how to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hint: rank is the dimension of the image

Answer (score 4):

If $v=Au$ is a *non-zero* vector in $\operatorname{Im} A$, it is a basis for $\operatorname{Im}A$, since it has dimension $1$. Hence its own image can be written 
$\;Av=\lambda v\;$  for some $\lambda$, which is the definition of an eigenvector.